# Is a kurtosis of 1 unique to a equiprobable two-point distribution?

Tags: variance, sample, central-limit-theorem, kurtosis

This question came up while having a look for a CLT for the sample variance which I found under [this link (Theorem 5.3.2)](https://hannig.cloudapps.unc.edu//STOR655/handouts/Handout-asymptotics.pdf) from another stackexchange question which I can't remember. The Theorem from the notes states
$\sqrt[]{n} \, \frac{ S_n^2 - \sigma^2 }{ \sigma^2 \; \sqrt[]{\kappa - 1}} \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} N\left( 0, 1 \right)$ with $\kappa = \frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}$. My Questions now are:
For which distributions is $\kappa = 1$? I only know of the equiprobable two-point distribution but I am confused if there are others.
What happens to the Theorem in this case? I mean $S_n^2$ will asymptotically approach $N\left( \sigma^2, 0  \right)$ but I am a little bit lost figuring out what that means. I mean it would be one-point distributed, right? But what does asymptotically mean in this case?
What I am trying to do is to arrive at a formula like $n \geq \left( z_{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}} \, \frac{\sqrt[]{\kappa - 1}}{\epsilon} \right)^2$ for the sample size $n$ where 
$z_{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}$ is the $\frac{\alpha+1}{2}$ quantil of the standard normal distribution. This should give me a sample size for which there is a probability of at least $\alpha$ that the sample variance of the $n$ samples taken has a relative deviation of less than $\epsilon$ from the variance $\sigma^2$ of the underlying population. But this only works for $\kappa > 1$ (at least I think so).
I guess I am just missing something crucial here because I do not have a lot of knowledge in this field so every help in understanding this is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the squares of standardized residuals from the mean: these are nonnegative, have a mean of $1$, and the fact that $\kappa=1$ implies their mean square is $1.$  Apply Jensen's Inequality to conclude that all values are $1$ almost surely, and you're done.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your reply. It took me some time to understand that. So after Jensen's Inequality we show $1 = \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \left( \frac{ X_i - \overline{X}_n }{S_n} \right)^2 \right)^2 \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \left( \frac{ X_i - \overline{X}_n }{S_n} \right)^4 = 1$ and we can conclude that the squares of the standardized residuals all equal $1$? Because instead of less or equal we have equality of the two expressions? And if the standardized residuals are $1$ or $-1$ then we must have have a two-point distribution.

Comment: That's just what I had in mind.  The equiprobability conclusion then follows easily.

Comment: @whuber First thank you again, I think I understood a bit more about how this works. I have another question though. Do we need Jensen's equality if we already concluded that both of the expressions are $1$ and therefore equal?

Comment: Just to check, I got the equiprobability conclusion by taking the expressions for $\mu_4$ and $\sigma^4$ for a two-point distribution and set them equal (because of the assumption that $\kappa = 1$). Then the points $a$ and $b$ are getting cancelled out and we are left with a cubic polynomial in $p$ that has zeros in $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ where we can rule out $1$ because we have a two-point distribution.

Comment: Equiprobability follows immediately from the fact that when the data are standardized, both squares equal $1.$

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it and I see now why equiprobability follows immediately. Just one last confirmation would be great. We use Jensen's inequality because of this property of it : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628386/when-jensens-inequality-is-equality. We have equality and use a convex function which is not affine so we can conclude that the random variable $\left( \frac{X_i - \overline{X}_n}{S_n} \right)^2$ must be constant almost surely and that is the reason why we use Jensen's inequality.